# PHP Strip Base64 images from string

Tags: php, image, base64, tinymce, strip

I am using a very simple PHP script to save content from a TinyMCE Text Editor, I have had various issues with this text editor, specifically with image uploads saving images as Base64. I am hoping I have now solved the problem although to cover my back and save me hours of time removing Base64 images from the database, I am trying to strip any Base64 images from the content uploaded to the database - Is this possible and is there a simple method to achieve this?

Here is what I have at the moment, I could remove all images fine, but when looking for Base64 images, the code fails.

```
if(isset($_POST['update_content'])){
    $blog_id = $_POST['blog_id']; 
    $blogcontent = $_POST['blogcontent'];
    
    $sql = "UPDATE `blog` SET `blog_content` = ? WHERE `blog_id` = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        
    }
    
    $blogcontent = preg_replace("/<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64[^>]+\>/i", "", $blogcontent); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $blogcontent, $blog_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

What I would like to do is remove any Base64 images from `$blogcontent` before it is uploaded?

Comment: I guess this would be enough to match any type of TinyMCE sent image: `(<img(?:[^>]*)(?=(src=(?:'|")data:image\/(?:[a-z]*);base64=(?:[^>]*)))(?:[^>]*)(?:\/>|><\/img>))` however, this is a "blacklist approach" and wouldn't be difficult to bypass if someone wanted to upload a base64 image. [Example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qXBfv9/1)

Comment: @Jaquarh thanks for the reply, would that ignore normal image tags and only remove those which are Base64 as that is the aim? I will test out the code later. There are a limited number of people with access to this blog system so internal security such as it being bypassed isn't too much of a concern.

Comment: Yes, it will strip out all base64 encoded images and leave any ordinary ones (: it will also not care about the positition of the src, may need some small adjustments if any proceed it but if TinyMCE is creating them, I doubt you'll need to adjust it (: I added a Regex101 link to show you what its doing

Comment: @Jaquarh I can't seem to implement that in to my code, as it displays an error when due to the " mark here: |")data. Are you able to submit it as an answer so I can reference the code at all? Thanks

Comment: You need to use \\ to escape them as regex is written as a string in PHP. [See an example of it over on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/iF479)